# Changing NameFormat in SAML 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2005, saml-2.0

We are using SAML 2.0. We are supposed to integrate with an external client.
The customer is requesting use to change the following

NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" instead of NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"

Can we do that. If yes, how?

Comment: You haven't provided enough info to answer. Per the spec this is acceptable. What tools are you using to generate your SAML Response?

Comment: Any answers for this question???

Answer (score 1):

*NameFormat* is an attribute of Attribute element under *AttributeStatement* element of SAML assertion. SAML Core Specification mentions three attribute name format identifiers:

1. urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified
2. urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri
3. urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic

Now, urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress is a name ID format identifier. It is used as the value of the attribute *Format* of either *NameID*, *NameIDPolicy*, or *Issuer* element.

When you mentioned that you want to replace urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic with urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress, it puzzles me because they are used for different purposes.

Perhaps you can clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

In your AuthnRequest, you should have something like:

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
 Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
 SPNameQualifier="xxx"
 AllowCreate="true"
/>
```

Change the format in there e.g. the format above is "transient".